# Removing entries from hashtable having duplicate values in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, hashtable

I am having a hashtable which is storing details of employees. I am reading the entire excel file in a single hashtable using the following code

```
  If(! emdetails.ContainsKey(empid))
   empdetails.Add(empid,line)
```

Where line contains other employee details such as name, qualification, etc.

After that i have to filter out few employees on the following condition and remove them from that hashtable.
The condition is: 
Employee id having same name should not be considered.
For example,

```
Employee  Id, First Name, Last Name

1, Emma, jones
2, Emma, jones
3,Tara, Smith
4,Tara P, Smith
5,Scott, Smith
```

Here 1,2,3 and 4 should be removed from my hashtable. I should not even conisder 3 and 4 also.

How do I do that .

Comment: If you have control over the excel file, shouldn't you remove duplicates in the file instead as in validate/sanitize it before uploading?

Comment: No i dont have control over the file